# Use core data entity in a countdown timer

Tags: loops, core-data, timer, countdown

I have 2 entities in core data to create countdown timers. `Timer` has an attribute called `timerName` and entity `Blinds`(changed from 'Times') has an attribute called `duration`.

Entities called

```
Timer <---->> Blind
```

and attributes called

```
timerName <---->> duration
```

with relationships called

```
blinds <---->>timer
```

I need to place the various durations into a countdown timer one at a time. When the first duration reaches 0 the next duration is fetched from core data and that is counted down to zero etc.

I am very new to Objective-C and core data but I know I need a loop and fetch request but don't know where to start. Any code examples would be appreciated. Thanks

EDIT

I have setup a fetchrequest in my model.m

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)frc_newTimer
{
if (_frc_newTimer) return _frc_newTimer;

    // Otherwise, create a new frc, and set it as the property (and return it below)
_frc_newTimer = [_cdStack frcWithEntityNamed:@"Timer"
                      withPredicateFormat:nil
                          predicateObject:nil
                          sortDescriptors:@"timerName,YES"
                    andSectionNameKeyPath:nil];

return _frc_newTimer;
}
```

Then in my view controller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Timer.h"
#import "Blind.h"

@interface BlindTimerViewController : UIViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>
{
IBOutlet UILabel *lblCountDown;
NSTimer *countdownTimer;
int secondsCount;
}
- (IBAction)StartTimer:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)ResetTimer:(id)sender;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger currentTimeIndex;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Model *model;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Timer *myTimer;
@end
```

then in view controller.m

```
@interface BlindTimerViewController ()

@end

@implementation BlindTimerViewController
@synthesize model = _model;
```

and

```
-(void) timerRun 
{
secondsCount = secondsCount -1;
int minutes = secondsCount / 60;
int seconds = secondsCount - (minutes * 60);

NSString *timerOutput = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2d:%.2d", minutes, seconds];
lblCountDown.text = timerOutput;

//need to add a label for the next blind in the coredata list and update it while in a loop......

if (secondsCount == 0) {
    [countdownTimer invalidate];
    countdownTimer = nil;
    }

}

-(void) setTimer{
    // Configure and load the fetched results controller
self.model.frc_newTimer.delegate = self;
self.model.frc_newTimer.fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"timerName LIKE %@", @"Sample Timer"];

//add code to get the first coredata item in the blinds list

secondsCount = 240; // i need to insert the CoreData Blinds HERE
countdownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerRun) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

and buttons (yet to be fully sorted) to start actions

```
- (IBAction)StartTimer:(id)sender
{
[self setTimer];

}

- (IBAction)ResetTimer:(id)sender {
    [countdownTimer invalidate];
    countdownTimer = nil;
secondsCount = 0;
lblCountDown.text = @"00:00";


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're running the countdown for a known `Timer`. In this case you don't need a fetch request as you have a relationship from the `Timer` to its set of `Times`, we can access it directly:

```
NSSet *times = self.myTimer.times;
```

We want to sort it so you can run the durations in some order:
(you might also want to check that the count of times > 0)

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"duration" ascending:YES];
NSArray *orderedTimes = [times sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[ sortDescriptor ]];
```

Next, we're going to need an instance variable to track where we are:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger currentTimeIndex;
```

With these parts, you can manage the process, and use an `NSTimer` to actually do the work. When the timer fires you go back to the time, get and sort the times, increment the index we're using, check the index is in range, get the duration and start the timer.

I'm going to be cheeky and say that if the expiring timer is nil, that means we're starting the process from scratch (it would be better to take the first case out into a specific method):

```
- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)expiringTimer
{
    [expiringTimer invalidate];

    NSInteger index = (expiringTimer != nil ? (self.currentTimeIndex + 1) : 0);

    NSSet *times = self.myTimer.times;

    if (times.count < index) {
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"duration" ascending:YES];
        NSArray *orderedTimes = [times sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[ sortDescriptor ]];

        double duration = [[[orderedTimes objectAtIndex:index] duration] doubleValue];

        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:duration target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    } else {
        // deal with the error
    }
}
```

Now you can start the countdown with `[self timerFired:nil];`

You haven't said what you're doing while the timers are running, that could change things quite a bit (like you want to display an update of the time on screen each second)...

If you need to fetch the timer from your Core Data DB, that's where the fetch request comes in:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = <#Managed object context#>;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Timer"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"timerName LIKE %@", @"Sample Timer"]];

NSArray *timers = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil]; // should really add the error...

Timer *myTimer = nil;

if (timers.count == 1) {
    myTimer = [timers lastObject];
} else {
   // we didn't find the timer, agh!
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the above code and explanation, I will try this in my project. Yes, I would need the display to update every second and I would also need to change another text field when the Times entity changes show the next in the list. Eventually I would need a sound to be activated when each time reaches 0. If I get anywhere with adapting your code, I'll post it.

Comment: You could use 2 timers, 1 running each second to update the UI and the other running as above. Or use a single timer running each second. Either way you'll need some instance variables to keep track of what should be on the UI. Like 'currentTimeIndex', 'currentTimeDuration' and 'currentTimeRemaining'.

Comment: I get an error saying Property myTimer not found on object TimerViewController.

Comment: 'myTimer' is just an example of what your timer instance might be called (hence - I'm assuming that you're running the countdown for a known Timer.) You need to know which timer you're running the countdown for somewhere.

Comment: I obviously need to learn a lot more about Objective C. I have previously added data to Core Data (created at runtime) for a Timer with a timerName of "Sample Timer" with some sample Times. How do I reference that stored Timer in this code?

Comment: I have edited my post to give what I have so far. I have a timer that updates the display but I need to add the core data object (duration) and a loop to change the coredata item.